# git shelving to remote repository

Tags: git, commit, shelve

I would like to know if it's possible to use git with the following workflow:

- locally clone a remote repository
- make local changes
- commit them locally
- save them remotely so as not loose changes and in case I want to continue work on another workstation

go on like this, until the feature is completely finished

then I would like to finally commit it, like if it were a single commit...

I'm talking about shelving, but saving the partial commits to the origin repository

is it possible (or recommend) to work like this with git???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, commit your changes to some named branch, and push that branch to the remote.

When you want to commit as a single commit, you can use `git merge --squash`.

Comment: It will be created in the remote when you push it.